# Caching images/data points on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, core-data

Is Core Data in iOS 5 still the optimal way of caching things such as images (and their related metadata) in addition to other client-side data on the iPhone, or is SQLite the way to go if not all of the cache is being loaded into native controls such as UITableView? Some of the data I am looking to cache will be loadable by a UITableView, the other half of it will not. I know Core Data shines more with its integration into a table view, but I was curious if it's still worthwhile to explore for caching structured data that would normally come from a third party service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS development, I would not use SQLite over Core Data.  Core Data has a large number of optimizations that would be time-consuming and difficult to implement yourself.  Caching images in Core Data really depends on the size of the images.  Thumbnails aren't too bad, larger images are.  [Core Data Programming Guide - Large Data Objects (BLOBs)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html) has more information.

iOS 5, also has the ability to store large objects in the file system, rather than the database.  If your project is targeting iOS 5+, I'd go that route.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CoreData to manage the cache, but keep the files on disk. Each app has its own Cache directory which does not get backed up when the user syncs.  I would be surprised if someone hasn't implemented this sort of thing already.